# have troubles with Make files

Tags: c, gcc, stm32f4discovery, codesourcery, openocd

I have some problems with `double`! Through terminal there is some query, that I should give some number (For example how much delay in per hour). If I give through terminal a number such as 1.1 h then it prints about -1173000! It should print only 1.1.

I think, maybe there is some problem with the `Makefile` from FreeRTOS. (because it doesn't compile through FreeRTOS to STM32F407 processor!)

I believe something on this line should be fixed!

```
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
```

Here is the complete code of `Makefile`:

```
# Optimization level, can be [0, 1, 2, 3, s]. 
#     0 = turn off optimization. s = optimize for size.
# 

OPT = 0

# Object files directory
# Warning: this will be removed by make clean!
#
OBJDIR = obj

# Target file name (without extension)
#TARGET = $(OBJDIR)/main
TARGET = $(OBJDIR)/STM32F4_Test

# Define all C source files (dependencies are generated automatically)
#
SOURCES += src/uart.c
SOURCES += src/ustime.c
SOURCES += src/main.c
SOURCES += src/startup_stm32f4xx.S
SOURCES += src/system_stm32f4xx.c
SOURCES += src/syscalls.c
SOURCES += src/modbus.c
SOURCES += src/test.c
SOURCES += src/get.c
SOURCES += src/heap_2.c

SOURCES += FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c
SOURCES += FreeRTOS/Source/queue.c
SOURCES += FreeRTOS/Source/list.c
SOURCES += FreeRTOS/Source/croutine.c
SOURCES += FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.c 

SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/misc.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_adc.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_can.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_crc.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_cryp.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_cryp_aes.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_cryp_des.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_cryp_tdes.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_dac.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_dbgmcu.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_dcmi.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_dma.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_exti.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_flash.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_fsmc.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_gpio.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_hash.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_hash_md5.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_hash_sha1.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_i2c.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_iwdg.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_pwr.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_rcc.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_rng.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_rtc.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_sdio.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_spi.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_syscfg.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_tim.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_usart.c
SOURCES += libs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f4xx_wwdg.c

OBJECTS  = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES))))

# Place -D, -U or -I options here for C and C++ sources
CPPFLAGS += -Isrc
CPPFLAGS += -IFreeRTOS/Source/include
CPPFLAGS += -Ilibs/CMSIS/Include
CPPFLAGS += -Ilibs/Device/STM32F4xx/Include
CPPFLAGS += -Ilibs/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc

#---------------- Compiler Options C ----------------
#  -g*:          generate debugging information
#  -O*:          optimization level
#  -f...:        tuning, see GCC documentation
#  -Wall...:     warning level
#  -Wa,...:      tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#    -adhlns...: create assembler listing
CFLAGS  = -O$(OPT)
CFLAGS += -std=gnu99
CFLAGS += -gdwarf-2
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections
CFLAGS += -fdata-sections
CFLAGS += -Wall
#CFLAGS += -Wextra
#CFLAGS += -Wpointer-arith
#CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
#CFLAGS += -Winline
#CFLAGS += -Wunreachable-code
#CFLAGS += -Wundef
CFLAGS += -Wa,-adhlns=$(OBJDIR)/$(*F).lst

# Optimize use of the single-precision FPU
#
# CFLAGS += -fsingle-precision-constant

# This will not work without recompiling libs
#
# CFLAGS += -fshort-double

#---------------- Compiler Options C++ ----------------
#
CXXFLAGS  = $(CFLAGS)

#---------------- Assembler Options ----------------
#  -Wa,...:   tell GCC to pass this to the assembler
#  -adhlns:   create listing
#
ASFLAGS = -Wa,-adhlns=$(OBJDIR)/$(*F).lst


#---------------- Linker Options ----------------
#  -Wl,...:     tell GCC to pass this to linker
#    -Map:      create map file
#    --cref:    add cross reference to  map file
LDFLAGS += -lm
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map,--cref
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
LDFLAGS += -Tsrc/stm32_flash.ld

#============================================================================


# Define programs and commands
TOOLCHAIN = d:/Programme/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_2011_09_ARM_EABI/bin/arm-none-eabi
CC        = $(TOOLCHAIN)-gcc
OBJCOPY   = $(TOOLCHAIN)-objcopy
OBJDUMP   = $(TOOLCHAIN)-objdump
SIZE      = $(TOOLCHAIN)-size
NM        = $(TOOLCHAIN)-nm
OPENOCD   = D:\Tools\openocd-0.7.0\bin\openocd-0.7.0.exe
DOXYGEN   = doxygen
STLINK    = tools/ST-LINK_CLI.exe
MKDIR           = d:\tools\unxutils\bin\mkdir.exe


ifeq (AMD64, $(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432))
  SUBWCREV = tools/SubWCRev64.exe
else
  SUBWCREV = tools/SubWCRev.exe
endif


# Compiler flags to generate dependency files
GENDEPFLAGS = -MMD -MP -MF $(OBJDIR)/$(*F).d


# Combine all necessary flags and optional flags
# Add target processor to flags.
#
#CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft
#CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb 
#

// kannst du mal nach dem problem suchen? Und dich ueber floating point probleme informieren?
// auf der ARM cpu oder spezielle dieser F407 cpu

CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
#CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb 


CFLAGS   += $(CPU)
CXXFLAGS += $(CPU)
ASFLAGS  += $(CPU)
LDFLAGS  += $(CPU)

# Default target.
all: setup gccversion build showsize


setup:
    $(MKDIR) -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(MKDIR) -p $(OBJDIR)\src
    $(MKDIR) -p $(OBJDIR)\FreeRTOS\Source
    $(MKDIR) -p $(OBJDIR)\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\GCC\ARM_CM4F
    $(MKDIR) -p $(OBJDIR)\libs\STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver\src


build: elf hex lss sym bin

elf: $(TARGET).elf
hex: $(TARGET).hex
bin: $(TARGET).bin
lss: $(TARGET).lss
sym: $(TARGET).sym


doxygen:
    @echo
    @echo Creating Doxygen documentation
    @$(DOXYGEN)

# Display compiler version information
gccversion: 
    @$(CC) --version


# Show the final program size
showsize: elf
    @echo
    @$(SIZE) $(TARGET).elf

# debug level
OOCD_CL=-d2
#OOCD_CL=-d3
# interface and board/target settings (using the OOCD target-library here)
## OOCD_CL+=-c "fast enable"
OOCD_CL+=-f interface/signalyzer.cfg -f openocd/stm32f4x.cfg
OOCD_CL+=-f openocd/config.cfg
OOCD_CL+=-c init -c targets
# commands to prepare flash-write
OOCD_CL+=-c "halt"
# flash-write and -verify
OOCD_CL+=-c "flash write_image erase $(TARGET).elf" -c "verify_image $(TARGET).elf"
# reset target
OOCD_CL+=-c "reset run"
# terminate OOCD after programming
#   OOCD_CL+=-c shutdown

# Flash the device  
flash: hex
#   $(OPENOCD) -f "interface/signalyzer.cfg" -f "openocd/stm32f4x.cfg" -f "openocd/config.cfg" -c "flash_image $(TARGET).elf; shutdown"
    $(OPENOCD) $(OOCD_CL)
#   $(STLINK) -c SWD -P $(TARGET).hex -Run


# Target: clean project
clean:
    @echo Cleaning project:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
    rm -rf docs/html


# Create extended listing file from ELF output file
%.lss: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo Creating Extended Listing: $@
    $(OBJDUMP) -h -S -z $< > $@


# Create a symbol table from ELF output file
%.sym: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo Creating Symbol Table: $@
    $(NM) -n $< > $@


# Link: create ELF output file from object files
.SECONDARY: $(TARGET).elf
.PRECIOUS:  $(OBJECTS)
$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo
    @echo Linking: $@
    $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) --output $@ 


# Create final output files (.hex, .eep) from ELF output file.
%.hex: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo Creating hex file: $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

# Create bin file :
%.bin: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo Creating bin file: $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@


# Compile: create object files from C source files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    @echo
    @echo Compiling C: $<
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(GENDEPFLAGS) $< -o $@ 


# Compile: create object files from C++ source files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    @echo
    @echo Compiling CPP: $<
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(GENDEPFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

# Assemble: create object files from assembler source files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.s
    @echo
    @echo Assembling: $<
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

# Include the dependency files
-include $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/*.d)


# Listing of phony targets
.PHONY: all build flash clean \
        doxygen elf lss sym \
        showsize gccversion \
        build elf hex bin lss sym clean clean_list setup program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the Sourcery CodeBench 2011.09 ARM EABI compiler supports that configuration. In particular, your FPU setting appears to use single-precision, and I'm pretty sure all the libraries included with that toolchain expect a double-precision FPU.

It's not that the compiler can't produce the code you ask for. The problem is that the toolchain doesn't include compatible libraries.

It's possible that I'm mistaken and the FreeRTOS folks have already built and bundled the missing pieces, but suspect not.

Comment: I understand. I used the Code STM32F1xx from FreeRTOS for my Board STM32F407, it does truely work with floating! But i changed the Code STM32F407 from FreeRTOS, the it doesn't work with floating?

Comment: I understand. I used the Code STM32F1xx from FreeRTOS for my Board STM32F407, it does truely work with floating! But i changed the Code STM32F407 from FreeRTOS, the it doesn't work with floating? Maybe it is because of different configuration of Mikefile. And i am not sure, what ist the problem? The problem is, with Code of STM32F107 from FreeRTOS does running, but not FreeRTOS running on Board. Then i changed the Code from CORTEX_M4F_STM32F407ZG-SK (from FreeRTOS ) FreeRTOS is running on Board. But the Floating doesn't work. so what do you think about this?